# Difference between `pattern` and `where`

Tags: laravel

In this instance, Im confused. dont they do exactly the same thing?
barr the fact that the one is filleted before and the other during

```
Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+');

Route::get('user/{id}', function($id)
{
    // Only called if {id} is numeric.
});
```

and

```
Route::get('user/{id}', function($id)
{
    //
})
->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define Global Patterns using pattern

If you would like a route parameter to always be constrained by a given regular expression, you may use the pattern method:

```
Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+');

Route::get('user/{id}', function($id)
{
    // Only called if {id} is numeric.
});

Route::get('product/{id}', function($id)
{
    // Only called if {id} is numeric.
});
```

while using where you need to define for each route like this

```
Route::get('user/{id}', function($name)
{
    //
})
->where('id', '[0-9]+');

Route::get('product/{id}', function($id)
{
    //
})
->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

so pattern is a thing which you can define if you are using it multiple times

Comment: Aaah. That make a lot of sense now. Thanks Anand.